# How Can I get a 0 Neutral in my Y Axis all the time like what ever value it takes?

Tags: c#, .net, math, charts

```
GetMaximum = Gain.Max(); <-- List of Value Numbers Random takes out the maximum
GetMinumumVal = Gain.Min(); <-- takes out the minimum

XAxisScale = GainCounter;   

if (XAxisScale % 10 != 0)
{
    XAxisScale = (XAxisScale - XAxisScale % 10) + 10; <-- round off to nearest highest 10th
}               
intervalXaxis = XAxisScale / 5; <-- divide interval by 5

//------------- Y Axis ---- which needs a 0 neutral ----- //

if(GetMinumumVal > -40)
{
    GetMinumumVal = -40;
    ConvertToPos = -40; <-- default lowest -40
}
else
{
    if (GetMinumumVal % 10 != 0)
    {
        GetMinumumVal = (GetMinumumVal - GetMinumumVal % 10) - 10;
    }
    ConvertToPos = Convert.ToInt32(GetMinumumVal) * -1;
}

//-------------//

if(GetMaximum > 60) 
{                   
    GetMaximum = Gain.Max(); 
    if (GetMaximum % 10 != 0)
    {
        GetMaximum = (GetMaximum - GetMaximum % 10) + 10;
    }
}
else
{
    GetMaximum = 60; <-- Default highest 60
}
Getinterval = (Convert.ToInt32(GetMaximum) + ConvertToPos) / 10;    <--  divide by 10 but i need to have zero neutral on it?? this is the problem

Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas.Add("Area1a");            
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.Titles.Add("Gain / Loss for Product XYZ");//
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.Series.Add("Gain/Loss");
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.Legends.Add("Gain/Loss");

Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.Series["Gain/Loss"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;

Count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Trade_Analyzer_Panel.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.Series["Gain/Loss"].Color = Color.Blue;    
    //Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.Series["Gain/Loss"].Points[Count].AxisLabel = Convert.ToInt32(Gain[Count]).ToString();
    Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.Series["Gain/Loss"].Points.AddXY(Count, Convert.ToInt32(Gain[Count]));                 
    Count++;
}

// -------- Horizontal ---------- //

Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].AxisX.Maximum = XAxisScale;
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].AxisX.Interval = 5; //intervalXaxis;

// -------- Vertical ---------- //

Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].AxisY.Minimum = Convert.ToInt32(GetMinumumVal);
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].AxisY.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(GetMaximum);
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].AxisY.Interval = 20;
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;

// set view range to [0,max]
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].AxisX.Maximum = XAxisScale;

// enable autoscroll
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].CursorX.AutoScroll = true;

// let's zoom to [0,blockSize] (e.g. [0,5])
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;

Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(0, 5);

// disable zoom-reset button (only scrollbar's arrows are available)
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;

// set scrollbar small change to blockSize (e.g. 100)
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = 100;
```

Should i use an interval on this? or what any idea how can i get a 0 neutral for the highest and lowest value of my Y Axis in the Chart.. i need help bad i got runned out of ideas sorry

Example:

60

40

20

0

-20

-40

but then if example lower gets a -70 it looks like this:

50

30

10

-10

-30

-50

-70

How can I get a neutral 0 on it no matter how the changes are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the vertical interval is 20

```
Trade_Analyzer_Panel.chart1a.ChartAreas["Area1a"].AxisY.Interval = 20;
```

this means your steps up the axis will be the lowest value plus multiples of 20. You will get 0 on one of the steps if your bottom value is a multiple of 20. What may work is

```
if(GetMinumumVal > -40)
{
    GetMinumumVal = -40;
    ConvertToPos = -40; <-- default lowest -40
}
else
{
    if (GetMinumumVal % 20 != 0)
    {
        GetMinumumVal = (GetMinumumVal - GetMinumumVal % 20) - 20;
    }
    ConvertToPos = Convert.ToInt32(GetMinumumVal) * -1;
}
```

Using 20 rather than 10.

Note that the modulus operator % behaves strangely for negative numbers see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation. If x is negative the x % 20 is a negative number. You may find things easier to use `Math.Floor(GetMinumumVal / 20)*20` which is the smallest multiple of 20 less than GetMinumumVal.

Comment: Sir how about if i have a formula like i take the max of a array and the min of an array if the min is a negative convert to positive add it up divide then by 10 line but should never loose the zero? is it possible??

Comment: It should look like this one:

VarMAX = VarARR.Max();
VarMIN = VarARR.Min();

Convert = VarMin * -1;

GetInterval = (VarMAX + Convert) / 10;

how can i assure it that zero is always neutral?

Comment: The reason you are loosing the zero is its starting on an odd multiple of 10. If the min is -90, -70, or -50 then 0 won't get a zero on a division of the scale. You must make it so the scale starts at -100, -80, -60 etc. To do that you need to calculate numbers mod 20.